# Need to check if there is string in front of the @ symbol

Tags: python, validation, email, input

Writing some code to check if an email has been entered in a correct way, I have all the code down to check is @ symbol and . are in the string, as well as the whole email being a certain length, but I cant seem to sort out some code that checks if there is any string before the @ symbol, for now if you even enter @gmail.com it comes as correct.

```
email = input ("Enter an email address for you account: ")
check2 = 0

if "@" in email:
    check2 = (check2)+1
else:
    check2 = (check2)

if "." in email:
    check2 = (check2)+1
else:
    check2 = (check2)

if len(email)>6:
    check2 = (check2)+1
else:
    check2 = (check2)


if check2==3:
    print ("Your email was accepted")
else:
    print ("Error")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
if email[0] == '@':
    check2 = check2
else:
    check2 += 1
```

And update the last if/else to

```
if check2 == 4:
    print ("Your email was accepted")
else:
    print ("Error")
```

Comment: It may be a good idea to strip() the input string first to avoid having only spaces before @. Like this `email = strip(email)`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can check if index of '@' in the entered email address is 0. If 0 that would indicate the first letter is '@'. Below is the code:

```
str = "@gmail.com"

if(str.index('@')==0):
    print("INVALID")
```

Comment: Thank you for this as well, I really appreciate your help